# add values into a 2D array from an 1D array in C++ using loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an 1D array and a 2D array with some values. I want to add the values of 1D array into the 2D array using a loop.

So far I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>          //for _kbhit
using namespace std;
#define MAX_N 100

int c[MAX_N] = {21, 12, 23, 34, 15, 16};

int b[MAX_N][MAX_N] = {
                        { 10 , 11 , 20 },
                        { 22 , 30 , 33 },
                        { 40 , 44 , 50 }, 
                        { 55 , 60 , 66 }
                      };
int main()
{

    int i,j,k,l;
    int idx = 0;

    for( i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ )
       {
           for( j=0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
              {
                  b[i][j] = c[idx++];
              } 
       }


    for ( k = 0 ; k < 2 ; k++)
    {
        for (l = 0 ; l < 3 ; l++)
        {
            cout << b[k][l] << " " ;
        } cout << endl;
    }
cout << "\n\nHit<enter> to finish";
while ( !_kbhit());
return (0);
}
```

It doesnt work as I want. The desised output is:

```
10 11 20
22 30 33
40 44 50 
55 60 66
21 12 23
34 15 16
```

Any help please?
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work because here `for( i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ )` you overwrite (not adding) things from the 2d array and then you print the 2 first rows of the 2d array `for ( k = 0 ; k < 2 ; k++)` You 're in c++ start using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your initial for-loop overwrites your table.  There is more code to really add, but in general look at this code below and see if it helps:

```
int nextRow = 4;
int itemsToAdd = 6;
int rowsToAdd = itemsToAdd/3;
int additional = itemsToAdd%3;  // just added as hint for incomplete rows
int totalRows = nextRow + rowsToAdd;
int idx = 0;

for( i=nextRow; i<totalRows ; i++ )
{
    for( j=0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
    {
        b[i][j] = c[idx++];
    } 
}
```

Finally, you need to update your output loop to use the totalRows variable.